# Newer Whatsapp version?

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp, nokia-lumia-535

On my dual sim Lumia 535(RM-1090) when I try to share winrar archives(.zip), it says that **The version of Whatsapp you are using does not support sharing of such files** But every time I go to store and check it says about Whatsapp that it is **installed** and nothing about updation. How can I cope-up with this situation? Another issue is that I am a programming student and when I try to send C code file (extension .C)or MATLAB code file(.m), it gives a similar **but not very exact** notification (See the screenshot). Now were I can find that version of whatsapp which fulfils all my needs and can send or recieve all types of files??? Or is there any trick to send such files via whatsapp????

[image]

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp does not support the transmission of **.zip** files at the moment. You can go into the **[Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/whatsapp/9wzdncrdfwbs)**, and check the application's description and change log to confirm that.

Comment: yeah, he should probably use other services like wechat line etc for now

Comment: if it doesnot support then it should give a message like**whatsapp dont support.....** but instead it says **this version of whatsapp.......**. Doesn't that make any difference?

Comment: I think that message is because whatsapp plans to support zip files in the future, so that message is already set, as they assumed nobody would try to send zip files..

Comment: Oh I see.......Thanks but message already set is completely out of my mind

Comment: But @kelvinelove See my edits.......... what would you say about this? Do whatsapp plans to share programming codes as well? :D

Comment: I doubt that, But we can never be sure what the future holds ;)